# How do you get iSCSI multipath to discover new LUNs that have not been partitioned yet?

Tags: linux, storage, storage-area-network, iscsi, fdisk

Oracle Linux 6.3 iscsi multipath shows LUNs with existing file system but not the raw block devices that have not been partitioned yet.

When I run multipath -ll it will show a LUN that has previously been formatted with its multipath just fine.  Oracleasm even discovered it and added it to its disks.  But I created new LUNs that should be visible as they are on the same initiator but they do not show up.

fdisk -l only shows the one drive that works.

Is there some iscsiadm command or something that shows all the block level devices the system knows about that might help me be able to fdisk the new LUNs?

I actually got this to work once before but lost the key factor that enabled me to fdisk the drive and create a partition on it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your target does not automatically inform your initiator about changes in that session (when new LUNs are added).

You can do this manually by executing:

```
iscsiadm -m node -I default -T iqn.san.domain.tld:target -R
```

which will rescan your active iSCSI session and new LUNs will appear as new block devices in system.